# Optimizing Maximum Likelihood Functions

Tags: r, optimization

I generated a dataset of 20 random points from a Normal Distribution, created the Maximum Likelihood Function corresponding to these 20 points, and then tried to optimize this function to find out the mean (mu) and the standard deviation (sigma).

First, I generated the random data:

```
y <- rnorm(20,5,5)
```

Then, I defined the maximum likelihood function:

```
my_function <- function(x) {
 
  n = 20
  
  a = -n/2*log(2*pi)
  b = -n/2*log(x[2]^2)
  c = -1/(2*x[2]^2)
  d = sum ((y-x[1])^2)     
  return( a + b + c* d)
  
}
```

Then, I tried to optimize this function three different ways - but all of these ways failed:

**Method 1:**

```
#load all libraries
library(pracma)
library(stats)
library(GA)

    steep_descent(c(1, 1), my_function,  maxiter = 10000)
   
$xmin
[1] NA

$fmin
[1] NA

$niter
[1] 10001

Warning message:
In steep_descent(c(1, 1), my_function, maxiter = 10000) :
  Maximum number of iterations reached -- not converged.
```

**Method 2:**

```
 optim(c(1,1), my_function)

$par
[1] -8.487500e+00  1.776357e-16

$value
[1] -5.559631e+34

$counts
function gradient 
     501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message 
NULL
```

**Method 3:**

```
# I redefined the function for the GA Library
my_function <- function(x_1, x_2) {
 
  n = 20
  
  a = -n/2*log(2*pi)
  b = -n/2*log(x_2^2)
  c = -1/(2*x_2^2)
  d = sum ((y-x_1)^2)     
  return( a + b + c* d)
  
}


GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  my_function(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(-20,20), upper = c(-20,20), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)

GA@solution
      x1 x2
[1,] -20 20
```

In all 3 methods, the right correct answer is never found - as a matter of fact, none of the 3 methods find anything close to the correct answer.

As per statistical theory, the correct answer (based on the randomly generate data for this question) should be:

```
> mu = mean(y)
> sigma = sd(y)

> mu
[1] 3.937513

> sigma
[1] 4.707227
```

What am I  doing wrong and how can I fix this (i.e. have the optimization methods return answers that are closer to the correct answers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `optim` and `steep_descent` perform minimization (you want maximization). In `GA` your parameters are fixed (ex. lower = upper = 20). To adapt your code:

```
my_function <- function(param, vec) {
  
  - length(vec)/2 * log(param[[2]]) - 1/(2 * param[[2]]) * sum((vec - param[[1]])^2)
}
```

**optim**

```
res1 <- optim(
  method = "L-BFGS-B",
  par = c(0, 1),
  fn = my_function,
  vec = y,
  lower = c(-20, 0.01),
  upper = c(20, 40),
  control = list(fnscale = -1)
)
```

negative value for `fnscale` will perform maximization.

**GA**

```
res2 <- GA::ga(
  type = "real-valued",
  popSize = 100,
  fitnes = my_function,
  lower = c(-20, 0),
  upper = c(20, 40),
  vec = y,
  maxiter = 1000,
  run = 100,
  optim = TRUE
)
```

It's good to put `optim=TRUE` for the use of local search method (package supports it only for real-valued problems)

**DEoptim**

You can also use differential evolution (it also does minimization):

```
res3 <- DEoptim::DEoptim(
  fn = function(param, vec) -my_function(param, vec),
  lower = c(-20, 0),
  upper = c(20, 40),
  vec = y,
  control=list(NP = 100, itermax = 1000))
)
```

results:

```
> res1$par
[1]  1.935102 18.683264
> res2@solution[1,]
       x1        x2 
 1.935101 18.683222 
> res3$optim$bestmem
     par1      par2 
 1.935101 18.683252 
>
```

(for comparable results seed is needed)

Comment: @ Det: Thank you so much for your answer! I have been studying it the whole day and have learned so much! I really like the way you defined the function using param[[1]] and param[[2]] collectively - I will have to keep this in mind! Thank you so much!